# PayflowPro Credentials not working

Tags: payment-processor, paypal, payflowpro

0.1 on Wordpress 4.9.
We have a payflow manager account.  I have confirmed that our credentials are correct. However when I enter them into Civi payment Processor and attempt to subscribe to a membership through civi, I get the error message you see in the screenshot.  I also included another screenshot to show the civi payflowpro settings I am using.  Is maybe the site url incorrect?

Thank you
[image]

[image]

Comment: The error message mentions [Payflo](https://www.payflo.com/) but in **Site URL** you have `https://www.paypal.com`, are you sure you have the right extension installed? Might be a typo in the extension too, but Payflo is a different company AFAICT. (And the Payflo extension could well be based on PayPal code ... who knows! If you're *really* using Payflo, link to the extension code you have installed?)

Comment: Nah, just looks like the CiviCRM code refers to PayFlow as payflo on one line. You could [start debugging there](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/3d04355de56e2293afda299bc4e00d5816010082/CRM/Core/Payment/PayflowPro.php#L531) ... the curl request has failed, possibly due to authentication but also possibly because of SSL or some other request failure.

Comment: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/24681/payflow-credentials same question over here

Comment: Chris,  do you use PayFlowPro on your Civi install?

Comment: No, sorry I don't. Some popular extensions are shown [here](https://stats.civicrm.org/?tab=sites), if PayPal works I'd expect it to be popular. [Source data](https://stats.civicrm.org/json/).