# Do you use PayFlowPro in Civi?

Tags: payment-processor, payflowpro

We are using civi 5.0.1 on Wordpress 4.9

My question is simple. I would just like to know if anyone here is or ever has successfully used PayFlowPro in civi.  We have a reason to believe that Civi is just not compatible with it, but I would like some confirmation.  that is all I am asking.

Thank you.

Comment: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/24667/payflowpro-credentials-not-working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PayflowPro Credentials not working](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/24667/payflowpro-credentials-not-working)

Comment: This is not the same question. In this question I would like to know if anyone else is actually using this set up successfully, Do you use this set up?

Comment: Understood, appreciate the edit to clarify how this one differs. No I don't use that processor. Good luck!